Copy a file portably across UNIX and UNIX-like systems with POSIX API (modeled after Boost's copy_file())
Overview:
Following the POSIX API, there are 2 versions of the function: unix_copy_file(), and unix_fcopy_file(). One works with file descriptors, and is preceded with f (like fchmod(), fchown(), fstat() et cetera), and the other with file paths (like chmod(), chown(), stat()).
Instead of inventing some new semantics, I have chosen to go with Boost's, or C++'s, copy_file() from filesystem, with some changes.
The function is documented in the below header.
I did not see the utility of copy_options::update_existing, and did not support it. And Boost's documentation also says:

[Note: When copy_options::update_existing is specified, checking the write times of from and to may not be atomic with the copy operation. Another process may create or modify the file identified by to after the file modification times have been checked but before copying starts. In this case the target file will be overwritten.]

Code:
unix-copy-file.h:
#ifndef UNIX_COPY_FILE_H
#define UNIX_COPY_FILE_H 1

#include <sys/types.h>

#define UNIX_NONE                   0b0000'0000
#define UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING     0b0000'0001
#define UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING          0b0000'0010
#define UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE_DATA       0b0000'0100
#define UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE            0b0000'1000

/**
 * io_fcopy_file() copies a single file from src_fd to dest_fd, using the copy
 * options indicated by options. 
 *
 * src_fd:  A file descriptor opened for reading.
 * dest_fd: A file descriptor opened for writing.
 * options: Copy options.
 *
 * Precondition: 
 *     options must contains at most one option from each of the following groups:
 *       - UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING or UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING
 *       - UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE or UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE_DATA
 *
 *
 * Effects: 
 *     Fail if:
 *       - src_fd is invalid, or does not correspond to a regular file or 
 *         symbolic link.
 *       - dest_fd is invalid, or does not correspond to a regular file or
 *         symbolic link.
 *       - src_fd and dest_fd correspond to the same file.
 *       - Both UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING and UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING are set.
 *       - Both UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE and UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE_DATA are set.
 *
 *     Otherwise, return successfully with no effect if dest_fd is valid and 
 *     (options & UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING) != UNIX_NONE.
 *
 *     Otherwise:
 *       - The contents and attributes of the file corresponding to src_fd are
 *         copied to the file corresponding to dest_fd; then
 *       - If (options & UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE) != UNIX_NONE, the written data and 
 *         attributes are synchronized with the permanent storage; otherwise
 *       - If (options & UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE_DATA) != UNIX_NONE, the written data
 *         is synchronized with the permanent storage.
 *
 * Returns:
 *     true if the file was copied without error, otherwise false.
 *
 * Note:
 *     - The UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE_DATA and UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE options may have a
 *       significant performance impact. The UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE_DATA option may 
 *       be less expensive than UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE. However, without these options,
 *       upon returning from unix_fcopy_file() it is not guaranteed that the
 *       copied file is completely written and preserved in case of a system
 *       failure. Any delayed write operations may fail after the function
 *       returns, at the point of physically writing the data to the underlying
 *       media, and this error shall not be reported to the caller.
 *
 *     - This copying is not done within the kernel, and would require 
 *       transferring data to and from user space. But it is portable across 
 *       all UNIX-like systems. 
 *
 *     - The seek position of both the source file descriptor and the
 *       destination file descriptors are restored before returning.
 *
 *     - Symbolic links are followed. */
[[nodiscard, gnu::nonnull]] bool unix_copy_file(const char src_path[restrict static 1], 
                                                const char dest_path[restrict static 1],
                                                unsigned char options);

/**
 * io_copy_file() functions exactly the same as io_fcopy_file(), except that it
 * works with file paths instead of file descriptors.
 *
 * src_path:  Path to the source file.
 * dest_path: Path to the destination file.
 * options:   Copy options. 
 *
 * Note: 
 *     If dest_path does not exist, and (options & UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING) ==
 *     UNIX_NONE, the file is created. */
[[nodiscard]] bool unix_fcopy_file(int src_fd, int dest_fd, unsigned char options);

#endif /* UNIX_COPY_FILE_H */

unix-copy-file.c:
#ifdef __linux__
    #define _GNU_SOURCE    /* For Linux's fallocate(). */
    #define HAVE_FALLOCATE 1
#endif  /* __linux__ */

#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200819L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700

#include "unix-copy-file.h"

#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* On POSIX systems on which fdatasync() is available, _POSIX_SYNCHRONIZED_IO
 * is defined in <unistd.h> to a value greater than 0. */
#if defined(_POSIX_SYNCHRONIZED_IO) && _POSIX_SYNCHRONIZED_IO > 0
    #define HAVE_FDATASYNC 1
#endif /* defined(_POSIX_SYNCHRONIZED_IO) && _POSIX_SYNCHRONIZED_IO > 0 */

#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    #define unlikely(EXPR)  __builtin_expect(!!(EXPR), 0)
    #define likely(EXPR)    __builtin_expect(!!(EXPR), 1)
#endif /* defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER) */

[[gnu::always_inline]] static inline bool is_fd_valid(int fd)
{
    /* F_GETFD is cheaper in principle since it only dereferences the
     * (process-local) file descriptor in kernel space, not the underlying
     * open file description (process-shared) which it refers to. 
     *
     * In particular, the specification suggests that it cannot be interrupted
     * by signals, nor is it affected by any sort of lock held anywhere.
     *
     * See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12340725/20017547 and cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/93683-checking-if-file-descriptor-valid.html#post678998 */
    return fcntl(fd, F_GETFD) != -1 || errno != EBADF;
}

[[gnu::always_inline]] static inline bool is_mode_regular_file(mode_t m)
{
    return S_ISREG(m);
}

[[gnu::always_inline]] static inline bool is_mode_symlink(mode_t m)
{
    return S_ISLNK(m);
}

[[gnu::nonnull, gnu::always_inline]] static bool is_equivalent_stat(
        struct stat st1[restrict static 1],
        struct stat st2[restrict static 1])
{
    /* According to the POSIX stat specification, "The st_ino and st_dev fields
     * taken together uniquely identify the file wihin the system." */
    return st1->st_dev == st2->st_dev && st1->st_ino == st2->st_ino;
}

/**
 * Flushes buffered data and attributes written to the file to permanent storage. */
static int fsync_eintr(int fd)
{
    int ret;

    do {
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__) && defined(F_FULLSYNC)
        /* Mac OS X does not flush data to physical storage with fsync(). 
         * See: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/fsync.2.html */
        ret = fcntl(fd, F_FULLSYNC);
#else
        ret = fsync(fd);
#endif /* defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__) && defined(F_FULLSYNC) */
    } while (unlikely(ret == -1) && ret == EINTR);

    return ret;
}

/**
 * Closes a file descriptor and returns the result, similar to close(). Unlike
 * close(), guarantees that the file descriptor is closed even if EINTR error
 * happens.
 *
 * Note: Some systems do not close the file descriptor in case the thread is
 * interrupted by a signal and close() returns EINTR. Other (most) systems do
 * close the file descriptor even when close() returns EINTR, and attempting to
 * close it again could close a different file descriptor that was opened by a
 * different thread. This function hides this difference in behavior. */
static int close_eintr(int fd)
{
/* HP-UX does not close the file descriptor when interrupted by a signal. 
 * See: https://www.unix.com/man-page/hpux/2/close */
#if defined(__hpux)
    int ret;

    do {
        ret = close(fd);
    } while (unlikely(ret == -1) && errno == EINTR);

    return ret;
#else
    return close(fd);
#endif  /* defined(__hpux) */
}

static ssize_t read_eintr(int fd, void *buf, size_t size)
{
    ssize_t ret = 0;

    do {
        ret = read(fd, buf, size);
    } while (unlikely(ret == -1) && errno == EINTR);

    return ret;
}

static ssize_t write_eintr(int fd, const void *buf, size_t size)
{
    ssize_t ret = 0;

    do {
        ret = write(fd, buf, size);
    } while (unlikely(ret == -1) && errno == EINTR);

    return ret;
}

static ssize_t write_all(int fd, const void *buf, size_t size)
{
    size_t wcount = 0;

    while (wcount < size) {
        ssize_t ret = write_eintr(fd, (char *) buf + wcount, size - wcount);

        if (unlikely(ret == -1)) {
            return -1;
        }
        
        wcount += (size_t) ret;
    }

    return (ssize_t) wcount;
}

/**
 * Flushes buffered data written to the file to permanent storage. */
static int fdatasync_eintr(int fd)
{
#if defined(HAVE_FDATASYNC) && !(defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__DARWIN__) && defined(F_FULLSYNC))
    int ret;

    do {
        ret = fdatasync(fd);
    } while (ret == -1 && errno == EINTR);

    return ret;
#else
    return fsync_eintr(fd);
#endif  /* defined(HAVE_FDATASYNC) && !(defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__DARWIN__) && defined(F_FULLSYNC) */
}

[[gnu::always_inline]] static inline bool set_file_perms(int fd, mode_t m)
{
    return fchmod(fd, m) != -1;
}

bool unix_fcopy_file(int src_fd, int dest_fd, unsigned char options)
{
    /* The behavior of C++'s filesystem::copy_file is undefined if there is more
     * than one option in any of options option group present in the valid
     * option groups, and perhaps Boost too. We define it and return false. */
    if (((options & UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING) != UNIX_NONE 
            && (options & UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING) != UNIX_NONE)
        || ((options & UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE) != UNIX_NONE 
            && (options & UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE_DATA) != UNIX_NONE)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!is_fd_valid(src_fd) || !is_fd_valid(dest_fd)) {
        return false;
    }

    if ((options & UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING) != UNIX_NONE) {
        /* Do nothing. */
        return false;
    }

    struct stat src_st;

    /* If source file does not exist or is not a regular file or symlink, fail. */
    if (unlikely(fstat(src_fd, &src_st) == -1)
        || !(is_mode_regular_file(src_st.st_mode) || is_mode_symlink(src_st.st_mode))) {
        return false;
    }

    struct stat dest_st;

    if (unlikely(fstat(dest_fd, &dest_st) == -1)
        || !(is_mode_regular_file(dest_st.st_mode) || is_mode_symlink(dest_st.st_mode))
        || unlikely(is_equivalent_stat(&src_st, &dest_st))
        || unlikely(!set_file_perms(dest_fd, src_st.st_mode))) {
        return false;
    }

    posix_fadvise(src_fd, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL);

    /* Save the original seek position of both src_fd and dest_fd. We shall seek
     * to restore them before returning in either failure or success case. 
     *
     * Do not check for errors as none from EBADF, EINVAL, ENXIO, EOVERFLOW,
     * or ESPIPE is possible. */
    const off_t src_orig_pos = lseek(src_fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    const off_t dest_orig_pos = lseek(dest_fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);

    /* Buffer size is selected to minimize the overhead from system calls.
     * The value is picked based on coreutils cp(1) benchmarking data described
     * here:
     * https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/d1b0257077c0b0f0ee25087efd46270345d1dd1f/src/ioblksize.h#L23-L72 */
    char buf[256u * 1024u];
    bool ret = false;

    for (;;) {
        ssize_t rcount = read_eintr(src_fd, buf, sizeof buf);
        
        if (rcount == 0) {
            ret = true;
            goto restore; 
        }

        if (rcount == -1 
            || write_all(dest_fd, buf, (size_t) rcount) == -1) {
            goto restore;
        }
    }

  restore:
    lseek(src_fd, src_orig_pos, SEEK_SET);
    lseek(dest_fd, dest_orig_pos, SEEK_SET);

    if (!ret) {
        return false;
    }

    if ((options & (UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE_DATA | UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE)) != UNIX_NONE) {
        return (options & UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE_DATA) != UNIX_NONE
            ? fdatasync_eintr(dest_fd) != -1
            : fsync_eintr(dest_fd) != -1;
    }
    
    return true;
}

/** 
 * Hints the filesystem to opportunistically preallocate storage for a file. */
static bool preallocate_storage(int fd, off_t len)
{
#ifdef HAVE_FALLOCATE 
    /* We intentionally use fallocate rather than posix_fallocate() to avoid
     * invoking glibc emulation that writes zeros to the end of the file. We
     * want this call to act like a hint to a filesystem and an early check for
     * the free storage space. We do not want to write zeros only to later
     * overwrite them with the actual data. */
    int ret; 

    do {
        ret = fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, len);

        /* Ignore the error if the operation is not supported by the kernel
         * or filesystem. */
        if (errno == EOPNOTSUPP || errno == ENOSYS) {
            return true;
        }
    } while (unlikely(ret == -1) && errno == EINTR);

    return ret != -1;
#else
    return true;
#endif  /* HAVE_FALLOCATE */
}

bool unix_copy_file(const char src_path[restrict static 1], 
                    const char dest_path[restrict static 1],
                    unsigned char options)
{
    if (((options & UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING) != UNIX_NONE 
            && (options & UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING) != UNIX_NONE)
        || ((options & UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE) != UNIX_NONE 
            && (options & UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE_DATA) != UNIX_NONE)) {
        return false;
    }

    int src_fd;

    /* open() follows symlinks by default. */
    if (src_fd = open(src_path, O_RDONLY), src_fd == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    int opts = O_WRONLY;
    int dest_fd;

    if (dest_fd = open(dest_path, opts), dest_fd == -1) {
        if (errno != ENOENT) {
            close_eintr(src_fd);
            return false;
        }

        /* File does not already exist. Create it. */
        opts |= O_CREAT | O_TRUNC;

        if ((options & UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING) == UNIX_NONE
            || (options & UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING) != UNIX_NONE) {
            opts |= O_EXCL;
        }

        if (dest_fd = open(dest_path, opts, 0640), dest_fd == -1) {
            if (errno == EEXIST && (options & UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING) != UNIX_NONE) {
                /* Do nothing. */
                close_eintr(src_fd);
                return false;            
            }

            close_eintr(src_fd);
            return false;
        }
    }

    struct stat st;

    /* unix_fcopy_file() calls fstat() too. Can we somehow reduce one syscall? */
    if (fstat(dest_fd, &st) == -1
        || (!preallocate_storage(dest_fd, st.st_size) && (errno == EIO || errno == ENOSPC))) {
        close_eintr(src_fd);
        close_eintr(dest_fd);
        return false;
    }
    
    const bool ret = unix_fcopy_file(src_fd, dest_fd, options);
    
    /* Ignore errors on read-only file. */
    close_eintr(src_fd);
    
    if (close_eintr(dest_fd) == -1) {
        /* EINPROGRESS is an allowed error code in future POSIX revisions,
         * according to https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=529#c1200. */
        if (errno != EINTR && errno != EINPROGRESS) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return ret;
}

Tests:
test-unix-copy-file.c:
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200819
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "unix-copy-file.h"

/* See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/338667/553881. */
#ifdef _AIX
    #error "Replace /dev/stdin with another file (not regular/not symlink)."
#else 
    #define NOT_ISREG_OR_ISLNK  "/dev/stdin"
#endif
/* _AIX */

[[noreturn, gnu::format(printf, 1, 2)]] static void fatal_error(const char fmt[static 1], ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

[[noreturn]] static void cassert(const char cond[static 1], 
                                 const char file[static 1],
                                 size_t line)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "Assertion failed: '%s' at %s, line %zu.\n", cond, file, line);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

#define BLOCK(...)      do { __VA_ARGS__ } while (false)

#define fatal(COND, FMT, ...)                                     \
    BLOCK(                                                        \
        if (COND) {                                               \
            fatal_error("%s::%d::%s(): " FMT, __FILE__, __LINE__, \
                __func__, __VA_ARGS__);                           \
        }                                                         \
    )
    
#define test(COND)                              \
    BLOCK(                                      \
        if (!(COND)) {                          \
            cassert(#COND, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        }                                       \
    )

static bool has_same_perms_path(const char path1[static 1], const char path2[static 1])
{
    struct stat st1;
    struct stat st2;

    fatal(stat(path1, &st1) == -1 || stat(path2, &st2) == -1,
        "error: fstat failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));

    return st1.st_mode == st2.st_mode;
}

static bool has_same_perms_fd(int fd1, int fd2)
{
    struct stat st1;
    struct stat st2;

    fatal(fstat(fd1, &st1) == -1 || fstat(fd2, &st2) == -1,
        "error: fstat failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));

    return st1.st_mode == st2.st_mode;
}

static bool has_same_contents(const char file1[restrict static 1], 
                              const char file2[restrict static 1])
{
    switch (fork()) {
        case -1: 
            fatal(true, "error: failed to fork child: %s.\n", strerror(errno));

        case 0:  
            execlp("cmp", "cmp", file1, file2, (char *)0); 
            _Exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        default: 
            int status; 
            
            fatal(wait(&status) == -1, "error: could not wait for child: %s.\n",
                strerror(errno));
            
            return WIFEXITED(status) != 0 && WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0;
    }

    unreachable();
}

static int create_temp_file(char temp[static 1])
{
    int fd;

    fatal((fd = mkstemp(temp)) == -1, 
        "error: failed to generate temporary file: %s.\n", strerror(errno));

    return fd;
}

static void test_unix_fcopy_file(void)
{
    static char temp1[] = "To-be-or-not-to-be.XXXXXX";
    static char temp2[] = "That-is-the-question.XXXXXX";
    const int valid_fd1 = create_temp_file(temp1);
    const int valid_fd2 = create_temp_file(temp2);
    const int invalid_fd = -1;

    /* Invalid src_fd. */
    test(!unix_fcopy_file(invalid_fd, valid_fd1, UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING));

    /* src_fd is not a regular file or symbolic link. */
    test(!unix_fcopy_file(STDOUT_FILENO, valid_fd1, UNIX_NONE));

    /* Invalid dest_fd. */
    test(!unix_fcopy_file(valid_fd1, invalid_fd, UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING));

    /* dest_fd is not a regular file or symbolic link. */
    test(!unix_fcopy_file(valid_fd1, STDOUT_FILENO, UNIX_NONE));

    /* Both UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING and UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING specified. */
    test(!unix_fcopy_file(valid_fd1, valid_fd2, UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING | UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING));

    /* Both UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE and UNIX_DATA_SYNCHRONIZE specified. */
    test(!unix_fcopy_file(valid_fd1, valid_fd2, UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE | UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE_DATA));

    /* UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING specified. */
    test(!unix_fcopy_file(valid_fd1, valid_fd2, UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING));

    /* src_fd and dest_fd are equivalent, same file descriptors. */
    test(!unix_fcopy_file(valid_fd1, valid_fd1, UNIX_NONE));
    test(!unix_fcopy_file(valid_fd2, valid_fd2, UNIX_NONE));

    /* src_fd and dest_fd are equivalent, different file descriptors. */
    int dup_valid_fd1;

    fatal((dup_valid_fd1 = dup(valid_fd1)) == -1, 
        "error: failed to get duplicate file descriptor with dup(): %s.\n", strerror(errno));
    
    test(!unix_fcopy_file(valid_fd1, dup_valid_fd1, UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING));

    /* Write something to valid_fd1, and reset seek position.  */
    fatal(write(valid_fd1, 
            "To quote Hamlet Act III, Scene III, Line 87: \"No.\"\n", 51) < 51,
        "error: failed to populate temporary file: %s.\n", strerror(errno));

    /* Reset the seek position first. No error possible in this case. */
    lseek(valid_fd1, 0, SEEK_SET);
     
    /* Test for success. */
    test(unix_fcopy_file(valid_fd1, valid_fd2, UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING | UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE));
    test(has_same_perms_fd(valid_fd1, valid_fd2));
    test(has_same_contents(temp1, temp2));

    fatal(unlink(temp1) == -1, "error: failed to unlink: \"%s\": %s.\n", temp1,
        strerror(errno)); 
    fatal(unlink(temp2) == -1, "error: failed to unlink: \"%s\": %s.\n", temp2,
        strerror(errno));

    close(valid_fd1);
    close(valid_fd2);
}

static void test_unix_copy_file(void)
{
    /* Perfect for this situation, they're deprecated for other reasons. */
    const char *const valid_path1 = tmpnam((static char [L_tmpnam]){}); 
    const char *const valid_path2 = tmpnam((static char [L_tmpnam]){}); 

    fatal(!valid_path1 || !valid_path2, 
        "error: could not generate temporary file names: %s.\n", strerror(errno));

    /* At least this does not exist in this directory. */
    static const char *const invalid_path = "caskncsaccskncasdbckcaksncbadska320cas.caskncas";   

    /* Invalid src_path. */
    test(!unix_copy_file(invalid_path, valid_path1, UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING));

    /* src_path is not a regular file or symbolic link. */
    test(!unix_copy_file(NOT_ISREG_OR_ISLNK, valid_path1, UNIX_NONE));

    /* dest_path is not a regular file or symbolic link. */
    test(!unix_copy_file(valid_path1, NOT_ISREG_OR_ISLNK, UNIX_NONE));

    /* Both UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING and UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING specified. */
    test(!unix_copy_file(valid_path2, invalid_path, UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING | UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING));

    /* Both UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE and UNIX_DATA_SYNCHRONIZE specified. */
    test(!unix_copy_file(valid_path2, invalid_path, UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE | UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE_DATA));

    /* UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING specified. */
    test(!unix_copy_file(valid_path2, invalid_path, UNIX_SKIP_EXISTING));

    /* src_path and dest_path are equivalent. */
    test(!unix_copy_file(valid_path1, valid_path1, UNIX_NONE));
    test(!unix_copy_file(valid_path2, valid_path2, UNIX_NONE));

    /* Now test for success. */
    test(unix_copy_file(valid_path1, valid_path2, UNIX_OVERWRITE_EXISTING | UNIX_SYNCHRONIZE));
    test(has_same_perms_path(valid_path1, valid_path2));
    test(has_same_contents(valid_path1, valid_path2));

    fatal(unlink(valid_path1) == -1, "error: failed to unlink: \"%s\": %s.\n",
          valid_path1, strerror(errno));

    fatal(unlink(valid_path2) == -1, "error: failed to unlink: \"%s\": %s.\n",
          valid_path2, strerror(errno));
}

int main(void)
{
    test_unix_fcopy_file();
    test_unix_copy_file();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

For testing the contents of the copied file, I simply used the cmp utility.
And the Makefile:
CFLAGS += -O3
CFLAGS += -s
CFLAGS += -std=gnu2x

CFLAGS += -Wall
CFLAGS += -Wextra
CFLAGS += -Warray-bounds
CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-value
CFLAGS += -Wno-type-limits
CFLAGS += -Wconversion
CFLAGS += -Wmissing-braces
CFLAGS += -Wno-parentheses
CFLAGS += -Wpedantic
CFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS += -Wwrite-strings
CFLAGS += -Winline

# Quieten warning about GCC seeing a one-liner function as un-inlinable.
CFLAGS += -Wno-attributes

CFLAGS += -fsanitize=float-cast-overflow
CFLAGS += -fsanitize=address
CFLAGS += -fsanitize=undefined
CFLAGS += -fsanitize=leak

CLANG_CFLAGS += -fsanitize=function
CLANG_CFLAGS += -fsanitize=implicit-unsigned-integer-truncation
CLANG_CFLAGS += -fsanitize=implicit-signed-integer-truncation
CLANG_CFLAGS += -fsanitize=implicit-integer-sign-change
CLANG_CFLAGS += -Wreserved-identifier

GCC_CFLAGS += -Wformat-signedness
GCC_CFLAGS += -Wsuggest-attribute=pure
GCC_CFLAGS += -Wsuggest-attribute=const
GCC_CFLAGS += -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn
GCC_CFLAGS += -Wsuggest-attribute=cold
GCC_CFLAGS += -Wsuggest-attribute=malloc
GCC_CFLAGS += -Wsuggest-attribute=format

GCC_CFLAGS += -fanalyzer

# Detect if CC is clang or gcc, in this order.
COMPILER_VERSION := $(shell $(CC) --version)

ifneq '' '$(findstring clang,$(COMPILER_VERSION))'
  CFLAGS += $(CLANG_CFLAGS)
else ifneq '' '$(findstring gcc,$(COMPILER_VERSION))'
  CFLAGS += $(GCC_CFLAGS)
endif

SRCS   := unix-copy-file.c test-unix-copy-file.c
TARGET := tests

test: $(TARGET)
    ./$(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)

.PHONY: test clean 
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

Or clone this repository: copy_file.

Valgrind reported no leaks or errors.
All the tests pass.
The sanitizers and analyzers are happy.

Review Request:

Bugs, missing error-checking, resource-leaks, wrong error-checking, optimizations, missing documentation, wrong documentation.

Is the decision to restore seek positions apt?

Have I commented the obvious too much?

Any function that can fail with EINTR that I have not checked?

Any C23 features that can make things easier, or shorter? How do I reduce duplication in unix_copy_file() and unix_fcopy_file()?

Are the bit flags okay as they are, or do I change them to a typed enum?


I would like to use ioctl_ficlone()/copy_file_range()/sendfile() on Linux, clonefile()/copyfile() on MacOS, sendfile() on Solaris, copy_file_range() on FreeBSD, and so on, but the code would become hard to reason about with 10 more #ifdefs. But I have no idea how to achieve it without having separate source files for each platform that fall back to using these routines if the syscalls fail and a lot of code duplication in each source file. Ideally, I'd like a single copyfile_unix.c/copyfile_unix.h instead of copyfile_linux.c/copyfile_linux.h, copyfile_solaris.c/copyfile_solaris.h...
Note: This code is not written by the experts in the C++ committee who develop Boost libraries, but by an amateur solo C programmer, so judge accordingly.

Is a sendfile() call maybe relevant here, so a large file can be transferred without dragging all its bytes into user space?

Yes, it is very relevant. But this solution is intended to be portable across all POSIX and POSIX-like operating systems. sendfile() is available on Linux, Solaris, and MacOS. MacOS's sendfile() does not allow out_fd to be a regular file, But I do not know of any major difference between Linux's and Solaris' sendfile(). Though MacOS has more interesting functions, namely copyfile()/fcopyfile() and clonefile(). Next post would be about copying files in Linux efficiently (from ioctl_ficlone() to copy_file_range() to sendfile() to this io_copy_file()).

HP-UX also has sendfile(), but that has the same semantics as MacOS's sendfile().

I have to think that someone has managed to implement file copying using POSIX shm_open(), with src filedesc backing from existing file, and dest filedesc mapped to the same memory. Not sure if that would offer us zero-copy benefits, though.

@J_H C++'s boost library falls back to using read() + write() as well. I do not see any implementation using shm_open().

Trivial: in unix_copy_file() it looks like there's a risk src_fd might be abandoned (not closed.)....

@Fe2O3 You're correct. I have fixed it. Thanks. Also added C++'s if with initialization statement (or whatever) without adding it to C (which it is likely going to be in the next revision). :)

@Harith You're free to code whatever/however you like. It's been my contention for a long, long time that devoting excessive attention to "guidelines", "qualifiers" and "rules of thumb" (eg: "braces", "goto" prohibitions, etc.) diverts attention from the ultimate goal: correct code. I'd rather work my way through gaining an understanding of a working, compact "code golf" solution, than admire a beautiful, syntactically correct code using all sorts of bells and whistles, but that, unfortunately, doesn't do what it's supposed to do... Each to their own, I guess... Cheers! :-) Keep on codin'

@Harith Some reading matter... Cheers! :-)

i advise against un-defining _POSIX_C_SOURCE and _XOPEN_SOURCE. If you have conflicting versions of the API selected, you want the compiler to tell you, not silently hide it from you. If anything, I’d declare the macros conditionally, only if the programmer hasn’t already specified another definition in the makefile or on the command line, and fall back to those versions by default.

Selecting _GNU_SOURCE to use a non-portable call seems to conflict with the stated goal of writing portable, POSIX-conformant code. However, if you do, you should declare it before including any system headers. Never include any system headers with conflicting feature-test macros.

@Davislor Indeed, but fallocate() is only called on Linux as an optimization. I do not wish to use posix_fallocate() for the reason mentioned in the comments in preallocate_storage(). About _GNU_SOURCE, does it go above _POSIX_C_SOURCE?

@Harith All feature-test macros should be defined before you #include any system header. I often put them in a file called "config.h" or similar. So long as they do not refer to each other, the order in which they are declared does not matter.

Should probably turn these into an answer, but one more I just noticed. #if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION >= C23_PLACEHOLDER misspells __STDC_VERSION__ the second time, and could just be #if __STDC_VERSION >= C23_PLACEHOLDER, as a macro would expand to 0 if undefined, or would implicitly expand to 1 if defined without an explicit value. Note that some compilers are likely to support [[noreturn]] even without C23 selected, so you might want to check that __has_c_attribute is defined and __has_c_attribute(noreturn) is true.

@Davislor #if __STDC_VERSION__ >= C23_PLACEHOLDER would emit a warning with -Wundef. But as the code is already assuming C23 support, I'd skip the checks altogether.

What is the goal of this code?
Looking at the implementation, there is a random set of features added on top of the raw copying of data. Why were some things implemented and others not? You do mention it is inspired by boost::filesystem::copy_file(), but your options are not a 1:1 match for Boost's options. Boost's copy_file() also only copies via paths, not via file descriptors.
So I wonder, what is the goal of your copy functions? Is it to provide a C implementation of Boost's copy_file()? If so you did more than necessary. Do you want to make some Swiss army knife of POSIX file copying? If so you did much less.
It would be a good idea to state the goals and requirements, both for yourself and for the users of your code.
Make proper error handling possible
Your functions only return bool, no error code that the caller can use to determine what exactly went wrong. You might think that they can use errno in a POSIX environment, but the problem is that there are code paths where you return false without ever setting errno, in which case errno can contain the value of some previous error, but the caller cannot tell this without always having to set errno = 0 before calling your functions.
Either return an error code like Boost's copy_file() can do, or make sure errno is always set before returning false.
Use Doxygen
You are documenting your code in the header file, which is great. It looks like it is in Doxygen format, but unfortunately it is not. In particular, you need to use @param and @return to tag the lines describing function parameters and return values.
Don't just use the Doxygen format, also run the Doxygen binary on your code, with errors enabled. This will tell you that you made several mistakes in your documentation, like documenting src_fd for the function that takes a src_path instead, and vice versa.
Note that you also mention io_copy_file() in the comments, but the function is actually named unix_copy_file(). Also note that UNIX != POSIX; there are operating systems that are not UNIX-like at all, but do support POSIX.
Incorrect use of restrict
You use restrict for src_path and dest_path, but there is no reason to restrict those pointers. They are both const so no writing to them happens anyway, but also consider doing something like:
const char path[] = "subdir/file";
unix_copy_file(path + 7, path, 0); // copy file into subdir

Sure, that's not the prettiest of code, but there is no reason to forbid it.
Be careful modifying file(descriptor) properties

Is the decision to restore seek positions apt?

It's good that you thought about that. Indeed, the caller might not expect that you modify the seek position. But there is more that you change that the caller might not expect. You are setting POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL, but maybe the caller already set it to something else, or expects it to be the default I/O policy?
On the other hand, you are not copying some properties that the caller might reasonably expect to be copied, like UNIX permissions, POSIX ACLs, and perhaps other metadata.
Consider other APIs
You mention Boost's copy_file(), but this is now part of the standard C++ library since C++17 as std::filesystem::copy_file(). It also added many more copy_options that would be nice to have. There is the even more capable std::filesystem::copy() that might also be interesting.
For copying file descriptors, consider emulating the API of sendfile(), which Linux and many BSDs have. It does away with some of the limitations of your unix_fcopy_file(), like working on things other than regular files and symlinks (such as device files, pipes and sockets). It also doesn't seek, which is important for file descriptors which don't support seeking. It would also avoid the code duplication between unix_copy_file() and unix_fcopy_file().

Some minor stuff

How to print __LINE__?
The type nor range of __LINE__ is not specified in C yet this token certainly acts like some source code integer constant (i.e. text) with a positive (or at least a non-negative value).  Very large values are quite unusual yet perhaps computer generated code may have a large file line count.
C allows a re-assignment for line counting with #line directive with the restriction:

The digit sequence shall not specify zero, nor a number greater than 2147483647.

OP interestingly uses the type size_t to receive the token.  As size_t deals with object and memory sizes, and not file sizing, I found that selection interesting.
C does have long ftell() which hints that a long was a good type for file sizes (and also the number of lines in a file), yet that have been augmented by fgetpos() to cope with files more than LONG_MAX in size.
I'd instead recommend unsigned long (to always handle attainable values above 2147483647) as a simply choice, yet size_t will certainly work for nearly all cases.
We could use uintmax_t, yet that is just too pedantic.
int main() {
#line 2147483646
  printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) __LINE__);
  printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) __LINE__);
  printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) __LINE__);
  long long ll = __LINE__;
  printf("%lld\n", ll);
}

Output
2147483646
2147483647
2147483648
2147483649


Of course that's the output of one particular compiler (one that's reasonably well-behaved in this regard).  Be wary of "proof by experimentation", especially in C!

fatal_error("%s::%d::%s(): " FMT, __FILE__, __LINE__ certainly looks okay (apart from the bizarre doubling of the ":").  It's just the test(COND) calling cassert() with size_t that's questionable here, yes?

@TobySpeight I think it is only the last 2 __LINE__ that may fall under  "proof by experimentation".  In other systems, I'd expect a wrap, compiler warning/error.  The cast nicely handles the wrap.

Yes, the last two outputs could produce different outputs on other systems, but the first two should be safe.

@Toby.Speight  I'd expect printf("%d\n", __LINE__); is an issue when the line is >= 2147483648 as the token may look like a long long and not an int.

I can't remember the rules of conversion for integer literals in a varargs call - so I'm glad none of my files ever reach that line number!  :)

Because this program works by reading and writing blocks of data (like dd), it tends to use more storage space than it should for copies of sparse files.  While it may be possible to detect runs of zeros and replace their writes with lseek(), I'm not sure that's a good use of developer time compared to selecting from the platform-dependent options (particularly given that they can be implemented much more efficiently - for some filesystems, we get a copy-on-write file meaning zero cost until one or other is modified).

Please follow the established naming conventions.  I'm particularly concerned with

#define fatal(COND, FMT, ...)  



#define test(COND)


Established convention is to use all-caps for the names of macros.  That helps alert programmers that these are text substitutions rather than functions, and they do not obey the rules of scope that other identifiers do.
Even though you've taken care to ensure they expand each argument once each, and have used the do … while (0) idiom to avoid misbound if, I don't think it's right to drop this convention.  (For one thing, these are "statement-like" rather than "function-like" due to the do … while (0) idiom).

At least on Linux you can use lseek() to detect the holes in sparse files.
